# java.sql.timestamp conversion to oracle array off by 1 hour

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, jdbc, timestamp

So this is a legacy system.
Oracle 11g,  java 1.7.0_291-b32,  CentOS 7.
I have an issue where the time is getting off by an hour and remains so for the entire year (this is not just around when the DST flip is).

This is java using jdbc calling a PL/SQL procedure with an array of Timezone with local timezone data types. Note, this used to work 100%.

So an array of java.util.Date is converted to an array of java.sql.Timestamp.

```
   public static java.sql.Timestamp[] toTimestamp(Date [] objs) {
        java.sql.Timestamp[] tsArray = new java.sql.Timestamp[objs.length];
        int i=0;
        for(Date d : objs) {
            if(d == null)
                tsArray[i] = null;
            else
                tsArray[i] = new java.sql.Timestamp(((Date)d).getTime());
            i++;
        }

    return tsArray;
}
```

...
I have confirmed that the array returned has the correct time.
The array is then converted into an oracle.sql.ARRAY object

```
ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( 'TIMEZONE_ARRAY', connection );      
        ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(descriptor, connection, CollectionsUtil.toTimestamp(array) );
```

Where 'Timezone_Array' is a defined type in the database which is an array of timestamp with local timezone.  It is when the conversion happens here that the time gets adjusted an hour off from what it should be.

To combat this.  I have first off, made sure my jdbc driver was the latest available for jdk 7.  I ran oracle's timezone updater tool to make sure the timezone definitions in the JDK/JRE where the latest. I'm pretty baffled how this is not right.

I saw a similar issue in the 11g database where I had to update the timezone definition files for the database at which point it was fine.   The timezone info i updated to for the JRE was 2021a so should be fine.  It feels like some definition mapping needs updated as this worked a month ago. (why i updated the timezone definition files)  At any rate if someone has a suggestion I'm all ears. thx!

Comment: It’s no doubt some time zone issue. Which are the default time zones of your JVM, your database session and your database server?

Comment: How do you check the "timestamp with local time zone" values, to know they are one hour off? What time zone is assumed for the inputs (and where is that attached to the timestamps coming from Java - in the Java code, or only after the data arrives in the database), and what is the time zone of the session in which you check the results? A mismatch between the time zone before conversion to "local" time zone and the time zone after conversion back from "local" time zone to session time zone is the most likely culprit, not something about the time zone files.

Comment: You can query the DB time zone (offset from UTC) with `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual;`

Comment: so. the timezone of the jboss server is Los_Angeles, as is the Database.   The session in java, the user is in this case is NewYork and the timezone is set to that. So let's say I am scheduling a reoccurring event that starts at Noon EST every day for, say 10 occurrences. An array of timestamps is constructed in java, I am attached to the Jboss server stepping through the code,  I can see that the times are in fact Noon.  At the instance that code is setting the Array to pass to oracle  I inspect this array BEFORE it is passed to the db. it is 1 hour off.

Comment: so the array of java timestamps are fine, but when the Oracle Array which is of type "table of timestamp with local timezone"  is initialized with that timestamp array the time gets mangled.  This has worked fine for years until recently..

Comment: ok a bit more understanding now.  So I tweaked the code to do an array of oracle.sql.timestampltz because i wanted more control/visibility of the timezone.  I see that that, for example my time is: 1617033600000 which is 12pm EST.  My connection says it is -5, that is wrong! Pacific is -4 right now from GMT.  so that's the problem.  working on solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.  No short way to sum this up.
I am dealing with dbtimezone --> Oracle's default timezone which is an offset from GMT (or should be).
My jvm's timezone which can be based off the system's environment (my application it's based off a configuration entry).
The user that logs into my system has their specific timezone they are in and their session is set to reflect this.
To do this, we used oracle's timestamp with local time zone.  It stores a date/time in the timezone (see dbtimezone) time with no timezone info about it.
Oracle will use what you have configured your connection's timezone to be in and automagically adjust the time displayed to the user for their timezone.
To top it off, this is in Java 7, and using crappy java.util.Date for much of it.
This whole system worked flawlessly for the last decade until this year.
First off.  I had to update the timezone info for the RDBMS.  That fixed all timezone's being passed as singleton's.  It did not fix an array of the same type being passed, however.
My work around was to use oracle's to_timestamp_tz and pass an array of strings.  The java.util.Date string representation using a SimpleFormater you can display the timezone.  I know that date is timezone unaware. BUT my session *IS* configured with the timezone and when you pull the string out will reflect that. (and the time being stored in the date is the timezone applicable time).
Since jdbc/java refused all attempts to get it to be non-retarded (it was changing the time to the dbtimezone but not doing ti right, was an hour off) I just pass this string and in the PL/SQL procedure to the to_timestamp_tz to put it in the timezone with local time zone field.  Oracle handles changing it from the timezone represented in the to_timestamp_tz to the database's without a hitch.
So I didn't *fix* the code but rather coded around the bug.
So a simple method to take the date array and return back an array of string.

```
public static String[] toTimestampString(Date [] objs, String timestampPattern) {
    int i=0;
    String[] tsArray = new String[objs.length];
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timestampPattern);
    for (Date d: objs) {
        if (d == null) 
            tsArray = null;
        else {
            tsArray[i] = formatter.format(d);
            i++;
        }
            
    }
    return tsArray;
}
```

This array is then passed into PL/SQL which basically does this: `to_timestamp_tz(p_start_datetime(i),timestampPattern)`

Where the timestampPattern in oracle is slightly different in java basically in java it's  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm XXX"
in PL/SQL it is: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi tzr'
but they mean the same thing.  I have tested in about 6 different user timezones daylight savings and AZ and other non-daylight and it is working 100%.
thx all hope this helps some other poor soul trapped in timezone hell.

Comment: one gotcha. make sure you specify all 3 "X" for the timezone offset